# My request letter sounds awkward and I'm not sure how to end it

Tags: grammar, writing, style

I'm not a native English speaker, and formal letter writing classes from my school days involved archaic grammar and language. When I write a formal letter to a native speaker, I'm constantly second guessing myself to make sure I don't come off as overly groveling.

Long story short I need help to make my request letter complete. How would you suggest ending it? Any other grammatical errors? (The letter is addressed to my former supervisor)

> Dear Dr. *****
>
> I hope you are doing well.
>
> As you may recall, I am a graduate of the ******** residency program
>   at ****** Hospital (July 201* - June 20*5  ) I am to writing to
>   request a letter of experience ( listing job duties, title, and dates
>   of employment ) which is required as a part of my visa application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

I hope you are doing well.

As you may recall, I am a graduate of the ******** residency program at ****** Hospital (July 201* - June 20*5) I am to writing to request a letter of experience (listing job duties, title, and dates of employment) which is required as a part of my visa application.

Please let me know if this is something that you can supply, and if so, whether you require any additional information.

Thank you in advance,

[your name]

Comment: You could also put:  "I write to request...".  This is a less common usage but is perfectly grammatical.